# A smartphone that is free of Google and Apple software and meets these criteria?

Tags: smartphones

I would be grateful for recommendations of a smartphone that meets the following criteria:

- 1. It is free of Google and Apple software or hardware.
- 2. It can run a web browser, preferably Mozilla Firefox.
- 3. It can run a textchat-videochat-messaging program such as Signal, Telegram, Viber, Skype, Line, or Whatsapp, either as an app installed on it or through through the web browser.
- 4. It can connect via a USB to USB cable to a laptop running Windows and when it does I will be able to see the phone's filesystem on the laptop and use the laptop to transfer files (of any kind I want) to and from the phone - and this can be done without either the phone or the laptop being connected to the mobile phone network, wifi, or any other equipment, whether by cable or wirelessly.
- 5. No use of cloud services is required.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, I don't know if something like that exists, but the only phones using Apple/Google hardware are the Pixel series (by Google) and the iPhone series (by Apple). You can install LineageOS though on some android phones, but that is based off of Google Android, although LineageOS does meet all other requirements and is FOSS.

(you can also maybe run ubuntu phone although that is not supported by the Ubuntu devs anymore)

Comment: Many thanks for your help with this. Am I right to infer from what you say that if I can get LineageOS running on any smartphone then I should be OK for pts 2-5, and if it's billed as "Google-free Lineage" (or some other Google-free version of Android, such as Volla) then I should be OK for point 1 too? The Ubuntu phone looks amazing, especially the way they frame it as a computer, which every smartphone is but to market it that way suggests they're aiming to meet some of the expectations I have, incl. pt 4.

Comment: It's not supported on all phones and all Android variants use Google Android as a base, so Google free Android does not exist. I have used LineageOS inside WayDroid for some time and it is ok for point 2-5

Comment: Thanks again. When you say that Google-free Android does not exist, does this mean just that all versions of Android contain some code written for Google, e.g. presumably the kernel, or that it is impossible to run any version of Android on an internet-connected device without that device connecting with a Google server?

Comment: All android devices contain some Google code, although the kernel is written by Linus Torvalds and he has never worked at Google. I think the biggest part written by Google is the API

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't realise Android was based on Linux. How strange that a version of Linux and an Apple-produced OS are in (and dominate) the mobile OS game and Microsoft aren't in it any more. I will investigate Lineage.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "Google software", a [**Google Pixel**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_(Google)) phone running **[GrapheneOS](https://grapheneos.org/)** might be a viable choice. Except for some hardware driver [binary blobs](https://redmine.replicant.us/boards/39/topics/15440), it is fully open source software.

Apart from the first point, it covers all of your requirements. In detail:

1. While GrapheneOS is based on the [Android Open Source Project (AOSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)#AOSP) and thus includes *a lot* of code written by Google software engineers, it doesn't include any proprietary Google apps like Google Play Services, Google Search, Gmail, etc.

   But obviously, the Pixel phones are "hardware from Google" (GrapheneOS currently [only supports Pixel phones out-of-the-box](https://grapheneos.org/faq#supported-devices)).
2. It can run any web browser supported on AOSP like the mobile version of Mozilla Firefox. It even ships an ungoogled and hardened version of the Chromium web browser called [Vanadium](https://grapheneos.org/features#vanadium).
3. GrapheneOS can run any AOSP-compatible app like the ones you mentioned. If you don't want to use [(sandboxed) Google Play Store and Services](https://grapheneos.org/features#sandboxed-google-play) to install them, you could also conveniently install them via [Aurora Store](https://gitlab.com/AuroraOSS/AuroraStore), an open source Google Play Store client.
4. For USB file transfers, GrapheneOS supports anything that AOSP does, like the [Media Transfer Protocol (MTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol).

   For file transfers over IP networks, you could also rely on more powerful solutions incl.

   - [KDE Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Connect) (allows to mount the phone's file system via [SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol))
   - [Croc](https://github.com/schollz/croc) (Android app is found [here](https://f-droid.org/de/packages/com.github.howeyc.crocgui/))
   - [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) (there are [two Android apps available](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/contrib.html#android))
5. GrapheneOS does not force you to use any cloud services. It also replaces Google servers with their own privacy-respecting ones for low-level stuff like connectivity checks etc. It provides [privacy by default](https://grapheneos.org/features#privacy-by-default).

[Installation of GrapheneOS](https://grapheneos.org/install/) is relatively easy and can be done using only the phone, a USB cable and a computer running a [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser))-based web browser like [ungoogled-chromium](https://ungoogled-software.github.io/) via [GrapheneOS' web installer](https://grapheneos.org/install/web).

Answer (score 1):

**KaiOS phones**

KaiOS is a derivative of Firefox OS, which does everything in the browser.

1. KaiOS uses Firefox on top of Linux.  No Google apps by default.
2. It runs Firefox
3. [There's](https://www.kaiostech.com/store/) WhatsApp, Facebook, Google Duo and other apps
4. If you plug in a KaiOS phone to a USB port, it shows as a USB storage device (not sure if it's mass storage or MTP)
5. I don't think it uses any cloud services, beyond those you use in specific webapps

[Nokia and others sell KaiOS phones](https://www.kaiostech.com/explore/devices/)